# Next-Auth for Cognito is not having access_token

Tags: reactjs, next.js, amazon-cognito, next-auth

I am using AWS Cognito as authentication provider for my Next.js (version 13) app, with the help of Next-Auth. When I try to login, it is getting successful, I am able to get the session using **useSession()** hook in the components.

But I do have a REST API secured with same AWS Cognito configuration. The idea here is to get the user Bearer token from the UI and pass it to the REST API, and get user specific info. Currently I am unable to get the **JWT token**, which I will be using to authenticate the REST API.

**app>api>auth>[...nextauth]>route.js**

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CognitoProvider from "next-auth/providers/cognito";

export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    CognitoProvider({
     clientId: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
     clientSecret: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_SECRET,
     issuer: process.env.COGNITO_ISSUER,
     authorization: {
       params: {
         scope: "openid",
       },
     },
}),
],
session: {
  jwt: true
},
secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
jwt: {
 encryption: true,
},
callbacks: {
  async jwt({ token, user }) {
   return { ...token, ...user };
  },
  async session({ session, token, user }) {
   session.user = token;
   return session;
  },
 },
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

When I use the **useSession** to print it to the console, I don't have information about the JWT token

[image: Console Output]

Answer (score 0):

You might need to check the `account` object that the `jwt` callback provides, you can find additional information, usually if the provider you use is returning a token, it will be found there:

```js
async jwt({ token, user, account }) {
  return {...token, ...user, ...account};
},
```

Also you have to add

```js
idToken: true,
```

to the provider object

Comment: I added this code to see what is available in account variable
`console.log({ token, user,account })`

The **user** and *account* variable is always _undefined_

Comment: So for where do you get the property 'email' of your final session?

Comment: Try it this way in the jwt callback `if(user & account){token.user = user; token.account = account} return token` and in the session callback `session.info = {...token.user, ...token.account}; return session` and see what the session looks like with useSession